# Adding and counting values from unique entries

Tags: excel

I am keeping track of donations for a non for profit... My spreadsheet looks like this:

```
          Date             Donor             Amount

  1       Date 1           Abe                 $50
  2       Date 2           Bob                 $50
  3       Date 3           Carlos              $450
  4       Date 4           Abe                 $50
  5       Date 5           Carlos              $50
  6       Date 6           Abe                 $1000
  7       Date 7           Abe                 $50
  8       Date 8           Bob                 $50
  9       Date 9           Bob                 $100
 10       Date 10          Daniel              $50
 11       Date 10          Abe                 $50
 12       Date 10          Carlos              $50
 13       Date 10          Daniel              $50
```

I would like to track donations from every unique donor.
I don't mind adding a column or even a sheet, but ultimately I would like to have something that says:

```
Donor A: 5    $1200   
Donor B: 3    $200
Donor C: 3    $550
Donor D: 2    $100
```

I also would like that to update automatically as I add donations **over time** and also **new** donors

Please advise.

Comment: Have a look into [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) and [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b). That should do it for you

Answer (score 3):

You really should consider a PivotTable for this before any alternative. Easy, quick and versatile:

[image: SO34279044 example]

It is **not** automatic but only requires two clicks to refresh.

Comment: Two clicks to refresh if he stores his data in either a named range or a listobject :)

Answer (score 0):

On a new sheet Copy and paste your donor list into A2.

Select the list then: Goto DATA --> Remove Duplicates.

Then in B2 put the following formula, Assuming you have a title row in row 1:

```
=CountIf(Sheet1!B:B,A2)
```

In C2:

```
=SumIf(Sheet1!B:B,A2,Sheet1!C:C)
```

Sheet1 is the name of the sheet on which you have the data.  Column B is where the donor list is on that sheet and the amounts donated is in Column C.

Then copy the formulas down.

This does require some work but not a lot.